# Subgroups of the Klein-4 Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Can anyone explain to me the subgroups of the Klein-4 group? I'm trying to view it this way:

I want some groups that are not empty and $ab^{-1} \in H$, where $H$ denotes the subgroups I am looking for.

So the Klein-4 group is as follows: $V_4 = \langle a,b : a^2 = b^2 = (ab)^2 = 1\rangle $. I'm a bit confused by the $\langle $ and $\rangle $ to denote a cyclic group but I sort of follow what's going on.

I guess the group itself and the trivial subgroup are there...But can you explain to me how to find the rest?

**Possible answer:**

Trivial subgoups $ \{\ e \}\ $ has order one.
Order 2: $\{\ e,a \}\ , \{\ e,b \}\ , \{\ e,ab \}\ $
Order 4: The group itself. As the order of the subgroups must divide the order of the group, these must be all the subgroups.

Comment: $<$ and $>$ denotes the presentation of the group, in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints:

[Lagrange's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_%28group_theory%29) says the only possible sizes of subgroups and orders of elements are $1,2,4$.

The identity element is one of the elements in each of the subgroups, and each element of order $2$ generates a subgroup of order $2$. Are there any elements of order $4$? By thinking about these ideas, you should see how to come up with your list.

The notation $\langle a,b,c,\ldots\mid\ldots \rangle$ is a special one for describing a [presentation of a group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_of_a_group). It is related to [set notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation) but is not exactly the same.

The letters in the left half denote the supply of symbols that generate the group. Multiplying these symbols just involves using exponents and writing symbols next to each other. For example, $a\cdot b=ab$, $ab\cdot b=ab^2$ and so on. So don't get me wrong: the left half isn't a complete list of what's in the group, it's a list of symbols that generate the group.

The equations in the right half are rules that control the behavor of the multiplication. For example in the Klein $4$ group, one of the rules is that $b^2=1$, so in fact $ab\cdot b=ab^2=a1=a$. These are called *relations* for this group, since they relate products to each other and control the group operation.

Comment: Isn't Klein-4 order 2?

Comment: After some reading, I can see that it is order 4, but how come? I'm having problems seeing that it is order 4.

Comment: @user3200098: it has four elements, clearly. What's confusing about that? Are you confusing the order of the group with its exponent, by any chance?

Comment: I realize that if $a$ and $b$ are strict numbers, then it has the elements: $a^2, b^2, (ab)^2$ and $1$. But my confusion stems from imagining $a$ and $b$ as any real numbers...And therefore the group could have endless elements...It works for $1$ and $-1$...I think I'm having a difficult time understand exactly what the klein-4 group is.

Comment: Like if I imagine the group $Z_4$ then I see the order $0, 1, 2, 3$ and it is obviously $4$, right? But it's confusing when it's $a$ and $b$ instead of numbers, because that makes me feel like it could be anything and therefore endless order.

Comment: @user3200098 Wow, it's pretty clear you have a lot of ideas about how to think about the elements of a group :) It sounds like you're thinking of them like "variables," but that is too complicated. The Klein 4 group is the set $\{1,a,b,ab\}$ with the multiplication rules $a^2=b^2=(ab)^2=1$. The things $a,b,ab$ aren't really "numbers," just think of them as "things" that you can multiply. They always obey these rules, and you can't switch them for things like $0,1,2,3$. They are not acting as placeholders, they are just symbols.

Comment: @user3200098 I also added some more to my solution: let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thank you. Is my answer correct in my edited post?

Comment: @user3200098 Yes, it is.

Comment: Thank you. I chose best answer.

A final remark: I see that the Klein-4 group is order 4 because it has 4 elements. I see that the trivial subgroup is order 1 because it has has 1 element, e. I'm having trouble seeing why $ \{\ e,a \}\ , \{\ e,b \}\ , \{\ e,ab \}\ $, the order 2 groups, do not contain groups such as $ \{\ e,1 \}\ $ and $ \{\ a,1 \}\ $ or perhaps $ \{\ a,b \}\ $ ?

Comment: And why is $ \{\ a \}\ $ not a order 1 subgroup of the klein 4?

Comment: @user3200098 because $\{a\}$ isn't closed under multiplication, and doesn't have identity.

Comment: Ah...So much information in abstract algebra that you need to keep track of! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user3200098 it's ok :)  After a while these things become like breathing, and you see the details work out more or less automatically. I wish you luck learning about more groups. It's a worthwhile journey!

Answer (score 2):

$G=\{e,a,b,ab\}$ the relation says that every nontrivial element has order $2$.

Thus,$H_1=\{e,a\}$,$H_2=\{e,b\}$,$H_3=\{e,ab\}$,$H_4=\{e\}$,$H_5=G$ are all subgroups.

The notation $<x,y,z..>$ means that group is generated by elements $x,y,z..$ if a group is generated by one elements then it is cylic.In that case, $G=<a,b>$ means every element of $G$ can be written in terms of $a$ and $b$ satisfying the given relation.