# subgroups of $\mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z$

Tags: group-theory

I calculated the subgroups of $\mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z$ as $\{ (0, 0 ) \}, \{ (0, 0 ), ( 1, 0 ) \}, \{ (0, 0 ), (0, 1) \}, \{ (0, 0 ), (1, 1) \}$ and $ \mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z$ and itself. I [googled](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100316200339AAQStlB) a bit and found couple of answers which did not include $\{ (0, 0), (1, 1)\}$. Isn't $\{ (0,0), (1,1)\}$ subgroup of 
$\mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z$ ?

Comment: $\{(0,0),(1,1)\}$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. And try not to use Yahoo Answers as a reference.

Comment: I tried to comment on that wrong answer, but wasn't able to. :(

Comment: @egreg next time google will direct to M.SE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct about $\{(0,0),(1,1)\}$ being a subgroup. Yahoo answers is not the best place to find answers to your math questions. I don't want to toot our own horn, but M.SE is a better place for this type of question, as evidenced [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/697722/subgroups-of-the-klein-4-group).

Comment: all right ,, thanks :) I am done